# What is need to improve percentage

Tags: microsoft-excel

I work in a school and attendance is something we wish to focus upon.  I would like to be able to calculate the following:

If a student's attendance falls below 90%, I would like to calculate in Excel **how many days of full attendance** would be needed to take that student's attendance back to 90%.

For example:

There are 2 sessions per day.

```
Possible Attendance =   140

Actual Attendance =     122

Percentage Attendance = 87.1
```

To get back to at least 90% attendance the student will need to fully attend the next 20 days to get back to 90%.

```
Possible Attendance=    180

Actual Attendance =     162

Percentage Attendance = 90
```

*(180-140)/2 = 20 School Days*

Is there a way to get the number of days needed?

I would also need to factor in week-ends and school holidays. Any guidance pointers would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

With the total in **A1** and the attended in **A2**, in another cell enter:

```
=ROUNDUP((0.9*A1-A2)/0.1,0)
```

This is the number of **incremental** days.  For example:

[image]

So the total days would become *20* and the attend days would become *18* and we would get *90%*

Let me know if you need help with the algebra behind the formula.

Comment: Divide it by 2 to get the number of *days*